# I want to add "n" lines from a file(say file1) into another file below the "n" occurrences of a string in another file in order

Tags: text-processing, sed

***Example***

File 1 :

```
This Dog
This Cat
This Duck
This Horse
```

File 2 :

```
...
Animal Name
...

AniMal Type
...

AnIMal Class
...

animal Brand
...
```

I want to do the following:

- add Line 1 of File 1 (This Dog) just below the 1st occurrence of "Animal" (Ignore case)
- add line 2 of File 1 (This Cat) just below the 2nd occurrence of "Animal" (Ignore case)
- add line 3 of File 1 (This Duck) just below the 3rd occurrence of "Animal" (Ignore case)
- add line 4 of File 1 (This Horse) just below the 4th occurrence of "Animal" (Ignore case)
- ...

So in general, line n of File 1 should be added just below the nth occurrence of "Animal" (Ignore case).

So, how do I achieve this using "sed" or "awk" or any command in Linux?

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed '/^animal/IR File1' File2
...
Animal Name
This Dog
...

AniMal Type
This Cat
...

AnIMal Class
This Duck
...

animal Brand
This Horse
...
```

where the GNU extensions are as follows:

> The I modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU extension which causes the regexp to be matched in a case-insensitive manner.

and

> R filename
>
> Queue a line of filename to be read and inserted into the output stream at the end of the current cycle, or when the next input line is read. Note that if filename cannot be read, or if its end is reached, no line is appended, without any error indication.

Comment: We learnt something new today...

Answer (score 1):

This **awk** solution should do the trick:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next};1;tolower($1)=="animal"{print a[++i]}' file1 file2 > file3
```

**NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}** accumulates file1 data in an array, skipping to next input line to prevent processing of file2 at this stage.

**1** prints each input line of file2.

**tolower($1)=="animal"{print a[++i]}** matches "animal" case-insensitively, and outputs the corresponding array item, pre-incrementing the array index.

Comment: This works flawlessly for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Sed**

Just append a `.` after the last line of `file_1` to signal the ending of file_1 to `sed` as `sed` has no concept of `FNR` of `awk`, IOW, `sed` the `POSIX` variety has no way of knowing when one file ends and the next starts.

The essential idea being to store the animal names in the `hold area` and then when the time comes to read in the `file_2` we grab each newline-separated portion of the `hold` & attach it to the `pattern space` and at the same time `detach` it from the `hold`. This `attach<->detach` exercise is taken only on the line that comprise the literal string `animal` in a case-insensitive` fashion.

```
sed -e '
   1{
      :file1
         N
      /\n\.$/!bfile1
      s///;h;d
   }

   /^[aA][nN][iI][mM][aA][lL]/!b

   G
   s/\n/&&/2;ta
   b

  :a
   h;s/.*\n\n//;x
   s/\n\n.*//

' file_1 file_2
```